# Bootstrap multiselect set selected options

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap

I use Bootstrap multiselect for my app, when loading the page, i need to retrieve data from database and pre-selected options based on the data. but i cannot get it works

here is the multiselect

```
$(@el).find('.fields').multiselect
  includeSelectAllOption: true,
  buttonWidth:'150px',
  maxHeight:350,
  buttonText: (options) ->
    if (options.length == 0)
      return "Select Fields"
    else 
      return options.length + ' selected'
```

here is the code how to select options

```
_.each data.fields, (dtfield) ->
  $(@el).find('.fields option:contains("#{dtfield}")').prop('selected', true)  <-- not working
  $(@el).find('.fields').multiselect('select', dtfield)  <-- not working either
```

thanks!

Ok, after couple of try, here is the updated code:

UI:

```
$(@el).find('.fields').multiselect
  buttonWidth:'150px',
  maxHeight:350,
  selectAllValue: 'all'
  buttonText: (options) ->
    if (options.length == 0)
      return "Select Fields <b class='caret'></b>"
    else 
      return options.length + ' selected <b class="caret"></b>'
```

select options:

```
selectedFields = (array of fields you want to select)
$(@el).find('.fields').multiselect 'select', selectedFields
```

Comment: @Cos: i've updated the post to include the solution.